# "Unresolved variable <variable>", allthoug the type of the object is declared

Tags: angular, typescript, webstorm

In Angular 17, I use

```html
@for (notification of notifications; track notification) {
   <i>{{notification.quotationId}}</i> 
}
```

but in WebStorm I get the warning

> Unresolved variable quotationId

In TypeScript, the type of the property `notifications` is set to `PendingQuotations`, which is:

```js
export type PendingQuotations = {
  quotationId: number,
  sender: string,
  date: string
}[]
```

Why do I get this warning?

This is how I set the property:

```js
export class HeaderComponent implements OnInit {
  public notifications?: PendingQuotations;

  constructor(private generalService: GeneralService) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.$getNotifications().subscribe((pendingQuotations: PendingQuotations) => {
      if (pendingQuotations.length > 0) {
        this.notifications = pendingQuotations;
      }
    });
  }

  $getNotifications(): Observable<PendingQuotations> {
    return this.generalService.get<Response>('/quotation/pending-quotations')
      .pipe(
        map((res: Response) => res.messages[0] as unknown as PendingQuotations)
      );
  }
}
```

This is is the value of `res`:

```json
{
    "code": "PENDING_QUOTATIONS",
    "status": "OK",
    "timestamp": "13.01.2024, 14:33:24",
    "messages": [
        [
            {
                "id": 1,
                "quotationId": 2,
                "receiver": "receiver@example.com",
                "sender": "sender@example.com",
                "date": "2024-01-13T09:27:59.256+00:00"
            }
        ],
        "I am a string"
    ],
    "token": null
}
```

Comment: Do you check if it ist set? The list ist optional. In general your approach is not so good. You should give observable to template and subscribe using async pipe. You still need to check if defined.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of `{{notification.quotationId}}`, you may use the following:

```
{{notification["quotationId"]}}
```

This is a quick-fix, which is also suggested by WebStorm.

Answer (score 0):

I believe all the problem lies in this part of the code:

```
public notifications?: PendingQuotations;
```

`notifications` is optional here and in the loop:

```
@for (notification of notifications; track notification) {
   <i>{{notification.quotationId}}</i> 
}
```

it is not checked for the `undefined` value

**The solution may be as follows:**

```
public notifications?: PendingQuotations;
```

or

```
@for (notification of notifications!; track $index) {
    <i>{{notification.quotationId}}</i> 
}
```